# 403 (Forbidden) when doing `s3cmd get` but `s3cmd ls` works

Tags: amazon-s3, s3cmd

I've set up `s3cmd` and can successfully put an encrypted file on S3 using it by doing this:

```bash
$ s3cmd put --encrypt --config=/home/phil/.s3cfg s3://my-bucket-name/my-dir/my-filename
```

The file is put there OK.

But when I try to `get` the file, this happens:

```bash
$ s3cmd get --config=/home/phil/.s3cfg --verbose s3://my-bucket-name/my-dir/my-filename
INFO: Applying --exclude/--include
INFO: Summary: 1 remote files to download
s3://my-bucket-name/my-dir/my-filename -> ./my-filename  [1 of 1]
ERROR: S3 error: 403 (Forbidden):
```

The `my-filename` is created, but with 0 bytes.

I can do `s3cmd ls` and get a directory listing, so I can access the bucket and directory.

Why can I not `get` the file? I must have missed something...

Comment: These days, it is recommended to use the official [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) rather than `s3cmd`.

Comment: Thanks John, I wasn't aware of that. It's hard to keep up with everything sometimes! A few hours later and I'm up and running again with the AWS CLI.